# Installing Android on VMware Workstation?

Tags: operating-systems, android, vmware-workstation

As you know , we can install different operating systems into Virtual Machines running under `VMware Workstation`.
Is it possible to install Android(4) on `VMware-Workstation 8`?

Comment: Check out the post [Can you run Android 2.2 Froyo or 2.3 Gingerbread in a VM?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5142/can-you-run-android-2-2-froyo-or-2-3-gingerbread-in-a-vm) at Android SE.

Comment: does it have to be vmware? I do believe there should be an emulator with the SDK that will emulate an ARM platform

Answer (score 4):

The quick answer is yes. You can run an x86 port of Android in a VMware virtual machine. There are several pages on the net that tell you what you have to do in order to get it to work. You'll have to configure things like IDE disks and such in the virtual machine to be sure that your virtual hardware is recognized by Android.

UPDATE: A quick google search for *android workstation* turned up what looks to be a pretty good [guide](http://quinxy.com/2011/03/12/running-android-2-2-in-vmware-in-less-than-5-minutes/). According to the guide, the virtual network adapter needs to be manually (i.e edit the vmx file) set to vlance (a pcnet32 driver is apparently in Android while an e1000 driver is not), and change the sound card should be changed to "SB X-Fi Audio"

Comment: So, could you please post some of useful links?

Comment: @Mohammad: Sure. done.